# How to get all data of documents with unique names in Flutter Firestore in same listview

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection ( reg_schools ) that has unique document names ( Liebenberg Primary School , St Michaels Primary School )  . Then those uniquely named documents has collection ( school_news ) with random document id names that has data too , and I would like to know if I can that all that data for collection 'school_news ' for both  Liebenberg Primary School and Michaels Primary School and have it in same listview   . Please see my image .

[image: firestore setup]

At the moment I only know of getting school_news data if I enter the unique document name in Streambuilder .

```
Container(
          height: 500,
          child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('reg_schools')
                .doc('Libenberg Primary School')
                .collection('school_news')
                .orderBy('created', descending: true)
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Center(
                  child: LinearProgressIndicator(),
                );
              } else
                return ListView(
                  children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((doc) {
                    return Padding(
```

So my question is , how can i  get all school_news data of both Liebenberg Primary School and St Michaels Primary School  in same listview ?

**UPDATE**

Created index as per answer given . And am able to get all the school_news collection data

Would I be able to do some filtering on what is returned with something like :

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collectionGroup('school_news')
        .where('name', arrayContainsAny: test)
        .snapshots(),
```

I will then have a list like :

```
List userSelections = ['Liebenberg', 'St Michaels' , 'School C' ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) to query documents in all subcollections of the same name, treating the entire set of documents as one unit.  Use [collectionGroup()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FirebaseFirestore/collectionGroup.html) for that.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collectionGroup('school_news')
    .orderBy('created', descending: true)
    .snapshots()
```

It is not possible to exclude any paths from that query.  You must take *all* subcollections with the given name.